# How to add comment without refreshing the page itself in django

Tags: python, django

I was making a blog website, I am new to django and I don't know how to add comment without refreshing the page itself. I was trying to do with the help of tutorial but they are not helping anymore
here is my html file

```
<div class="row">
<div class="comment-section col-8">
  {% for i in data %}
  <li>{{i}}</li><br>
  {% endfor %}  
</div>
<div class="col-4">
  <h4 class="m-3">{{comments.count}} Comments...</h4>
  {% for j in comments %}
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{j.title}}</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{{j.visitor.name}}</h6>
      <p class="card-text">{{j.description}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
  <hr>
  <h3>Comment here</h3>
  <form  method="post" id="comment-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" id="contentId" name = 'contentId' value="{{ result.id }}">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="hidden" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{request.session.user.name}}" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="title">Title</label>
      <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="description">Description</label>
      <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

here is my views.py file

```
def addComment(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    post_id = request.POST['contentId']
    title = request.POST['title']
    description = request.POST['description']
    user = request.session['user']['id']
    con = Comment(
        post_id=post_id,
        title=title,
        description=description,
        visitor_id=user,
    )
    con.save()
    print()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Comment: here is your answer :
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49628116/how-to-display-a-comment-after-posting-it-without-page-refresh-in-django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49628116/how-to-display-a-comment-after-posting-it-without-page-refresh-in-django)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display a comment after posting it without page refresh in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49628116/how-to-display-a-comment-after-posting-it-without-page-refresh-in-django)